# Can't scp files with long/weird filenames: Invalid argument

Tags: unix, scp, vfat

When I try to use scp to copy files with long filenames and containing non-alphanumeric characters, I get

> scp: open local "[some capricious filename]": Invalid argument

I can copy them some places, but I can't copy them onto a USB thumb drive.

Why can I copy some files some places and not others?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the USB thumb drive is formatted with a FAT file system that can't handle these file names.  They're legal in a modern file system, but illegal in file systems that are commonly used for USB sticks.  Scp tries to open the file for writing and the OS complains.

Comment: *Ergo*, format the USB NTFS if that is the issue. Not the most efficient for small flash drives, but should work.